# Accessing char* elements

Tags: c

I have this simple C code:

```
char *foo = "ABCDEFGH";
foo[2] = 'Z';
printf("%s\n", foo);
```

I expect the output is:

```
ABZDEFGH
```

I got this error:

```
Segmentation fault
```

I know `char *` is pointer and different with `char[]`.
In my real project, `foo` is variable that come from function that return `char *`. That's why I ask.

The question is how do I achieve what I expect in output?

Comment: `char *foo = "ABCDEFGH";` is a pointer to a string literal - you are not allowed to modify a string literal. You need to first copy it to something that can be modified, e.g.: `char foo[] = "ABCDEFGH";`

Comment: `char foo* =` is not valid syntax

Comment: You are not compiling the same piece of code shown in the question.

Comment: @UnholySheep according duplicate question refference _will place "Hello world" in the read-only parts of the memory, and making s a pointer to that makes any writing operation on this memory illegal._ But I'm working on embedded system, I wonder if such illegal is just Operating System rules?

Comment: Whether it works or not is dependent on whether the string literal will be in read-only memory or not. On some platforms it might work, but on many it will not. You should know the embedded system you're developing for. It appears to me that you skipped the basics.